# Excel =Sheet1! to stay locked to a specific column of data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in excel;

1. Sheet1: Data sheet where all the data is imported (we will call this 'Master')
2. Sheet2: sheet where I compare specific columns ('Comparison')

I need to copy in columns E and H from my Master to Comparison, starting at E3 and H3. To do this I use =Sheet1!E3 for each value (=sheet1!E4, =sheet1!E5 etc., etc.) going down. However, whenever I import data into Master, I insert another column and start new in E, moving all the data to the right.
Now the issue is, the =Sheet1!E3 formula doesn't stay as =Sheet1!E3 but rather follows that data. I import 3 columns per data set, once it's copied in, the =Sheet1!E3 will turn into =Sheet1!H3. I need this formula to stay as E3.
I have tried $E3 but the same thing happens.

What other formulas can I use to copy in data from another sheet but stay restricted to the first column of data?
I have also thought about writing a macro (or at least trying as I know nothin about VBA code). If this is easer, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!E" & ROW())
```

This won't change when you insert new columns before column E.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! does the '& ROW()' pull data from the row its typed in? like if I have '=INDIRECT("Sheet1!E" & ROW())' typed into row 5, it'll pull data from Sheet1 E5?

Comment: Correct, it will. If you want to pull row data from a different row (e.g. the row below), put a cell reference in there (such as E6) and it will return that cell's row instead.